# overflow: auto esconde o conteudo no final da página

Tags: html, css, rolamento

Estou com um problema no meu html, não consegui encontrar uma resposta. Tenho uma div chamada `box-footer`. Essa div fica dentro de uma div main, onde eu adicionei `overflow: auto` e `height 100%`. Todo esse conteúdo fica dentro uma div pai, `box-notification`, que eu também adicionei `height 100%`, mas a div `box-footer` o conteúdo fica escondido que seria um botão laranja. Consigo resolver o problema usando umas "gambs".

```
<div class="box-main">
    <div class="box-content">
        <div class="box-text">
            <p>teste
                <p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-footer">
        <button id="load-notifications" class="button btn">Load more notifications</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o Botao é pra ficar fixo no rodapé?

Comment: sim, mas ele nao esta fixo, é um div que fica no final de todo o conteudo, o que fica fixo é essa div com o texto "notification".

Comment: Consegue compartilhar o seu css usado?